# My iCloud account name and AirDrop name do not match

Tags: icloud, airdrop

I use my Apple ID on both a MacBook Pro (for work) and an iMac (at home). Here is the screenshot of my ID in System Preferences on my MBP.

[image]

It looks fine.

However my son at home had done a certain thing on the iMac with the ID and this problem appears:

In AirDrop on other Mac PCs, I see the following:

[image]

The user name is somehow changed to my son's name.

I have tried

1) login/logout of the iCloud account

2) resetting the profile picture.

But it was unable to reset the name. Everything else seems ok - I can AirDrop files to and from the iMac without a problem.

How can I fix this issue? Where does AirDrop pick up the name other than from my iCloud settings?

Comment: Besides the incorrect name is everything working ok? That is, can files be transferred just fine via AirDrop? Both to and from the iMac?

Comment: Yup. I can’t even get my pictures to sync either, so there’s clearly some split happening on a per device basis. There is no functional breakage, but it’s a little irritating to not be able to control your name or icon.

Comment: @Monomeeth The airdrop functionality is ok

Comment: Check the name under the _Users & Groups_ System Preference pane.

Comment: it only shows my login i.e. not my name. Also the picture there is inconsistent yet again with my icloud settings

Answer (score 1):

Try opening Sharing under System Preferences, then change the name there. It should change your AirDrop name.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences → Users and Groups → Contacts Card: Open, and edit the name.